# Customizing labels in FusionCharts

Tags: fusioncharts

I'm using FusionCharts to display the Bar2D chart in my app. Below is what I'm getting.

[image: FusionChart]

As you can see the labels are not getting wrapped properly, and since the labels are long, the bars gets shortened.

I tried using the {br} to wrap the label text but in that case also, and below is what I got:

[image: FusionChar1]

But because of the wrapping, the text is not getting aligned properly. It looks haphazard. Can anyone suggest a way to wrap these labels and also left align the text. I know that labels cannot be aligned but if anyone know any workaround to left align, please do let me know.

Below the xml:

```
<chart caption='' plotSpacePercent='63' labelPadding='50'  showhovercap='0' yaxisname='' xaxisname='' showValues='0'  yAxisMinValue='0' showBorder='0' showLegend='0'  anchorAlpha='0'  bgColor='"+bgcolor1+","+bgcolor2+"' canvasBgColor='"+bgcolor1+"' showCanvasBg ='0' showCanvasBase='0'  setAdaptiveYMin='1' borderThickness='0' baseFont='Arial' baseFontSize ='9' baseFontColor ='"+fontColor+"' outCnvbaseFontColor='"+fontColor+"' showAlternateVGridColor='0' showAlternateHGridColor='0' plotGradientColor='"+plotGradiantColor+"' plotBorderColor='"+plotBorderColor+"' showPlotBorder='1' divLineThickness='0' borderAlpha='0' canvasBorderAlpha='0'  canvasBorderThickness='0' bgAngle='0' bgAlpha='0' canvasbgAlpha='0' canvasBgAngle='0' connectNullData='1' exportEnabled='1' exportShowMenuItem='0' exportAtClient='0'  exportHandler='"+exportHandler+"'  outCnvbaseFontSize='11' exportAction='Download'  divLineAlpha='0' formatNumberScale='0' showYAxisValues='0' chartLeftMargin='1' chartRightMargin='5' chartTopMargin='1' chartBottomMargin='1' labelDisplay='WRAP'>
<set name='Brazil Real Estate/Property' value='200' color='2B465B'/>
<set name='Department Store Retailing' value='195' color='2B465B'/>
<set name='Vale SA.' value='190' color='2B465B' />
<styles>
    <definition>
        <style name='myCaptionFont' type='font' font='Arial' size='11'  bold='1' underline='0' />
        <style name='myAnim' type='ANIMATION'  start='$canvasStartX' param='_x'/>
    </definition>
    <application>
        <apply toObject='DataLabels' styles='myCaptionFont,myAnim'/>
    </application>
</styles>
</chart>
```

I'm new to FusionCharts. I may be missing something obvious but please help.

Comment: Could you please try adding the desired space after the "label" by trial & error method to see if this helps?
Please try using "label" attribute instead of the "name" attribute.

Comment: For Flash chart, please try using "maxLabelWidthPercent" attribute in the chart element.

Comment: @Sanjukta - the label names are dynamic. We would never know how long the names are, so adding space by trial n error wont be a good option.

Comment: @Swarram - i tried using the "maxLabelWidthPercent". it adds ellipses after that specified width instead of wrapping it.

Comment: Also, the labelsDisplay="WRAP", wraps the the labels even mid-word, for example "Brazil Real Estate/Property" may end up looking like:  
"Brazil Re  
al Estate/  
Property"

Answer (score 0):

I used `&#10;` to add a newline to the labels on trendlines.

Example:

```
<trendlines><line displayValue='Brazil Real&#10;Estate/Property' .... /></trendlines>
```